# How can I make the Tapped event of a TextCell open up another page?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have defined a TextCell like this:

```
public partial class MyTextCell : TextCell
{
    protected override void OnBindingContextChanged()
    {
        base.OnBindingContextChanged();
        var item = BindingContext as CategoryGroupWordCountVM;
        if (item != null)
        {
            this.Text = item.Name;
            this.Detail = App.DB.GetTotalWordCountBySelectedCategories(item.Id).ToString();
            this.StyleId = "disclosure";
        }
    }
}
```

I added an add a tapped event like this:

```
section = new TableSection("Select from Available Categories");
            foreach (var category in categoryGroups)
            {
                var cell = new CategoryGroupTextCell { BindingContext = category };
                cell.Tapped += openCategoriesPage();
                section.Add(cell);
            }
        }
        tableView.Root.Add(section);
```

I have an openCategoriesPage method:

```
    async void openCategoriesPage(object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Item == null) return;
        var categoriesPage = new CategoriesPage();
        var categoryGroup = e.Item as CategoryGroupWordCountVM;
        ((ListView)sender).SelectedItem = null;
        await Navigation.PushAsync(categoriesPage);
    }
```

However I have a problem in that I get an error saying that:

> CategoryGroupPage.xaml.cs(36,36): Error CS7036: There is no argument
>   given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'sender' of
>   'CategoryGroupPage.openCategoriesPage(object, ItemTappedEventArgs)'

Can someone advise me if I am doing the opening of the next page correctly and also what could be the cause of my error?

Comment: The line `((ListView)sender).SelectedItem` will throw an exception; as the sender is `TextCell` in this case.

Comment: Hi Sharada, What should I put for the sender? Should I change that to (TextCell) ?  By the way I made the change suggested by hankide but still get an error saying: No overload for 'openCategoriesPage' matches delegate 'EventHandler' (CS0123)

Comment: Hi Anne, I don't believe you need this line `((ListView)sender).SelectedItem = null;` - as TableView or TextCell don't have concept of selected item. As for the compiler error - you need to change line `async void openCategoriesPage(object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs e)` to `async void openCategoriesPage(object sender, EventArgs e)`. Basically the argument type for `e` is `EventArgs`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should subscribe to the Tapped event with the method name alone (without the parentheses), like this:

```
cell.Tapped += openCategoriesPage;
```

It's the same as doing the following:

```
cell.Tapped += new EventHandler(openCategoriesPage);
```

The compiler will generate the same IL code for both but the first one makes more sense if you want to unsubscribe from the event handler in the future (which you most likely will).

Comment: When I make the change you suggested I still get a message saying:   Error CS0123: No overload for 'openCategoriesPage' matches delegate 'EventHandler' (CS0123)

Comment: @Anne Did you try this one? `cell.Tapped += openCategoriesPage;`?